# Got confused about the While loop in python

Tags: python, while-loop

The while loop really made me confused.
It said while loop will execute when the condition is True. So, according to the following algorithm, will the message be printed only when we didn't enter 'quit', right? However, when I entered 'quit', quit was still printed before ending the loop.

Why? Any introduction to the while loop? Thanks!

```
prompt = "Please let me know what toppings you prefer?"
prompt += "Enter 'quit' to end the order. "
message = ""
while message != 'quit':
    message = input (prompt)
    print (message)
```

Comment: You ask for input, then print that input, then the loop condition is checked and then the loop ends. So you always print what gets entered. The loop just controls if you ask for input again or not.

Comment: Because you take the input, print the message, then test the value.  Just swap the last two lines.

Comment: The loop condition is only tested at the _beginning_ of each loop.  If the condition becomes false partway through the loop, that will not cause the loop to stop immediately.  It will finish that loop cycle.

Comment: There are probably a huge number of these questions - we need to identify or create a proper canonical duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is the supposed behavior because, the checking for while condition will only happen every time the loop completes.

```
while message != 'quit':    #3. Loop again for condition checking here
  message = input (prompt)  #1. Your input is 'quit' here
  print (message)           #2. 'quit' gets printed
                              
                            #4. found that the condition is false and finally breaks the loop
```

So for your case, I guess it is that you don't want to print the 'quit' message after typing 'quit' on the console, you can do it this way:

```
while True:
  message = input (prompt)
  if message == 'quit':
    break
  else:
    print(message)
```

Using a forever continuous loop but with a condition checking within itself, along with the use of `break` keyword when the condition meets.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you execute the while loop your `message` variable is not equal to `"quit"` so the inside part will execute

you may wanted to do this:

```
prompt = "Please let me know what toppings you prefer?Enter 'quit' to end the order. "
while message:=input(prompt) != "quit": print(message)
```

This uses the [walrus operator in python 3.8 release](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html)

Comment: The code you gave doesn't function correctly. prompt 2 is appended to the end of prompt 1, instead of being prompted separately.

Comment: Thanks, i removed the "\n" i thought that was the intent.

Answer (score 0):

#### You can try this

```py
# This code creates an empty list called "prompts" and then appends two strings
# to it, representing prompts for the user. 
prompts =[]
prompts.append("Please let me know what toppings you prefer?")
prompts.append("Enter 'quit' to end the order. ")

# An empty list called "responses" is created to store the user's input
responses = []

# The code enters a while loop which will continue until the string 'quit' 
# is entered by the user
while 'quit' not in responses:
    # for each prompt in the prompts list, the code will ask the user for input
    # and append the input to the responses list
    for prompt in prompts:
        responses.append(input(prompt))
```